# Will moving files or folders into another file in github mess contribution history?

Tags: git, github

If I want to create new folder and move my files and repositories to that new repository in github(for organisation purpose if I want to move more repositories into one newly created repository/folder), will that affect my contribution history calendar?

I tried looking at documentations for this but I didn't find anything about contribution history

**EDIT**:
I dont want to merge two repositories into one, I just want to create new folder and move some of my repositories(lets say project1, project2 and project3) into that newly created folder, and I still want my 3 projects to be a separate repository, but just withing that newly created folder(so not dependent of each other).

For example if I have a bunch of projects in my github page lets say project1, project2, project3(every project is one separate repository), and if I want to create new folder or new Organizations and move them into that new Organization or folder that I want to put those projects in, will that mess my contribution calendar?

Comment: history is recorded in the `.git` folder in the root of the repo, not the file contents.  So yes, copying the files tracked by the repo into another repo will lose all git history.  You can merge the repositories together though.  I think [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: @erik258 it does help in a way to solve my problem so thx, but I see its 14 years ago so I hope github did something about this problem and made it easier to move files and folders into another repository without losing history and without using subtree merge. So it does help me acomplish what I need, but it doesnt answer my question because history is recorded as you said in .git so I want to know will moving that with the whole repository into another repository's folder lose my history?

Comment: Each git repository has a separate .git and the only way to combine them is to use a `git` operation like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: @erik258 if I understand correctly the question that you provided on the link asks to merge repository A to repository B so that repository B uses some of the code of repository B but I dont want that I just want to reorganise my github repositories and put them in a newly created folder and I still want all of them to be separate repositories(I edited question for better clarification), will that mess my github calendar?

Comment: "so that repository B uses some of the code of repository B "   It doesn't matter whether the contents of the repo are related.  If you want the *history* of the repos to be shared, you need to merge the history with one of those methods